# Required Appropriate query to find out the result

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I need a desired result with the less number of execution time.
I have a table which contains many rows (over 100k) , in this table a field name is notes varchar2(1800).
It contains following values:

```
notes
CASE Transfer
Surnames        AAA : BBBB  
Case Status     ACCOUNT TXFERRED TO BORROWERS
Completed Date  25/09/2022
Task Group      16
Message sent at 12/10/2012 11:11:21
Sender      : lynxfailures123@google.com
Recipient   : LFRB568767@yahoo.com
Received    : 21:31 12/12/2002
```

Rows should return with the values of(ACCOUNT TXFERRED TO BORROWERS).

I have used the following queries but it takes a long time(72150436 sec) to execute:

1. `Select * from cps_case_history where (dbms_lob.instr(notes, 'ACCOUNT
   TFR TO UFSS') > 1)`
2. `Select * from cps_case_history where notes like '%ACCOUNT TFR TO
       UFSS%'`

Could you please share us the exact query which will take less time to execute.

Comment: When you say rows. How many rows of data? and how much time it takes to execute the above 2 queries? -update the question with more details

Comment: Hi  Mahendar Mahi, It has more thank lakhs rows, and execution time is 72150436 sec/mins i guess. could u pls help me out on this.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try parallel hints. [Optimizer hints](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41573/hintsref.htm)

```
Select /*+ PARALLEL(a,8) */ a.* from cps_case_history a
where  INSTR(NOTES,'Text you want to search') > 0;  -- your condition
```

> Replace 8 with 16 and see if the performance improves further.

Avoid `%` in beginning of the `like` operator
 ie., `where notes like '%Account...'`

**Updated answer :** Try creating partition tables.You can go with range partitioning on `completed_date` column  [Partitioning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/partconc.htm)

Comment: Hi, this query is same like my query. could u pls share some other query. or could u explain why did u comment parallel(4). i have no iddea about this query u given. i have tried this query but unable to get any result.

Comment: It is not a comment, it is hint .try the updated answer. @SelvaKumar

Comment: Hi  Mahendar Mahi , I have tried this query, but unable to find any differnce in performance improves. i have used to the follwing query select * from cps_case_history . it returns cardinality(execution-time) values is 26158. when i use select /*+PARALLEL(a,8)*/ a,* from cps_case_history a. gettting same execution time. could u pls suggest me some other query.

Comment: did u try elect /*+PARALLEL(a,16)*/ a,* from cps_case_history a.

Comment: also are there indexes present in the table. One other suggestion is to add  create partittion. see the updated answer